# SET Clause error #1054 - Unknown column in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, xml

Can anyone help me with this. I am loading an XML file into MySQL, the columns names are not the same so I am trying to use the SET clause but I keep getting an error saying Unknown column name "ReferenceNo" in field list?

This is the MSQL Query

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'C:/modified.xml' 
INTO TABLE wp_posts ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<Course>'
SET ID = ReferenceNo,
    post_title = CourseName,
    post_type = 'course';
```

This is a snippet of my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Course>
    <ReferenceNo>64055</ReferenceNo>
    <ProviderCode>CO</ProviderCode>
    <ProviderName>Training Centre</ProviderName>
    <CourseID>CO123</CourseID>
    <CourseName>IT Maintenance - Short Course</CourseName>
    <CourseTypeID>1</CourseTypeID>
    <CourseTypeName>1</CourseTypeName>
    <LocationCode>70203</LocationCode>
    <LocationName>Address of Training Centre</LocationName>
    <StartDate>2015.12.07</StartDate>
    <FinishDate>2016.03.04</FinishDate>
  </Course>
```

Comment: Is the order in which elements appear within each `<Course>` guaranteed to always be the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`LOAD XML`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-xml.html) documentation does not explain very well how the column list and `SET` clauses are applied.  It simply states:

> The following clauses work essentially the same way for [`LOAD XML`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-xml.html) as they do for [`LOAD DATA`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html):
>
> - `LOW_PRIORITY` or `CONCURRENT`
> - `LOCAL`
> - `REPLACE` or `IGNORE`
> - `CHARACTER SET`
> - `(column_or_user_var,...)`
> - `SET`
>
> See [Section 13.2.6, “LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html), for more information about these clauses.

The documentation for [`LOAD DATA`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html) states:

> By default, when no column list is provided at the end of the [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html) statement, input lines are expected to contain a field for each table column. If you want to load only some of a table's columns, specify a column list:
>
> ```sql
> LOAD DATA INFILE 'persondata.txt' INTO TABLE persondata (col1,col2,...);
> ```
>
> You must also specify a column list if the order of the fields in the input file differs from the order of the columns in the table. Otherwise, MySQL cannot tell how to match input fields with table columns.

It is not obvious how this translates to `LOAD XML`, since (unlike delimited files) fields need not appear in a consistent order throughout an XML document.  Furthermore, even if the fields *are* in a consistent order, simply specifying the respective names of the columns into which you wish for such fields to be loaded *does not work*.

The documentation goes on to say:

> The column list can contain either column names or user variables. With user variables, the `SET` clause enables you to perform transformations on their values before assigning the result to columns.

This approach *does* work with `LOAD XML`, so *provided that the elements appear in a consistent order throughout the document* one could do the following:

```sql
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'C:/modified.xml' 
INTO TABLE wp_posts ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<Course>'
(@ReferenceNo, @z, @z, @z, @CourseName)
SET ID = @ReferenceNo,
    post_title = @CourseName,
    post_type = 'course';
```

However, I think it might be more stable (and sensible) to go via a temporary table that maps more directly onto your XML schema:

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_courses_xml (
  ReferenceNo    INT UNSIGNED,
  ProviderCode   CHAR(2),
  ProviderName   VARCHAR(255),
  CourseID       VARCHAR(15),
  CourseName     VARCHAR(255),
  CourseTypeID   INT UNSIGNED,
  CourseTypeName VARCHAR(255),
  LocationCode   INT UNSIGNED,
  LocationName   VARCHAR(255),
  StartDate      CHAR(10),
  FinishDate     CHAR(10)
) ENGINE=MEMORY;

LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'C:/modified.xml'
  INTO TABLE tmp_courses_xml
  ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<Course>';

INSERT INTO wp_posts
  (ID, post_title, post_type)
SELECT ReferenceNo, CourseName, 'course' FROM tmp_courses_xml;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_courses_xml;
```

Comment: Hi eggyal, thank you for your help, the temp table is def the way to go I think because I need to insert data from the same table into multiple tables so it has ticked all the boxes for me. Really Appreciate the help thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually map the XML to the table, and this assumes that each row will be in the same order.

You cannot use a "SET" clause and refer to the rows by the xml attribute name.  That would be nice but appears to be a limitation of the current implementation.

So you want something like this.  In this case I shorten the example to the first 4 columns, you can expand out the rest.   I also select the 5th XML column into a variable @var1 so we can use it later, I'm not sure you need this but it's an example of how you get the data from the XML into a variable, to later use in SET -- though that is mainly helpful if you need to modify the data in some way, if you are just remapping names then you do that anyway with this syntax.  I also set your static post_type column.

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'C:/modified.xml' 
INTO TABLE wp_posts ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<Course>'
(ID, ProviderCode, ProviderName, CourseID, @var1)
SET
  test_column=CONCAT('test', @var1),
  post_type='course';
```

Comment: Hi Trent, thank you for your reply and taking the time to help. This has been a big help because I do have to manipulate some of the data at a later stage. .